# on a fn call in c++, args are copied to the corresponding parameter. Is this initialization or assignment?

Tags: c++, function-call

on a function call in c++, arguments are copied to the corresponding parameter. Is this initialization or assignment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Argument passing semantics are that of initialization. Meaning, your classes' copy/move constructors will be invoked.

Comment: Not always a copy constructor is called. `myfunc(MyClass(3))` will invoke only the MyClass(int) constructor.

Comment: You're (almost always) right. That's actually a compiler optimization, I believe, although almost all of them will actually do it ;)

Comment: g++ -O0 still does this "optimization".

Comment: I only meant the compiler will do it because it's actually silly to create the temporary and then invoke the copy constructor to create another object. I'm not entirely sure the language's standard requires the implementation to do that, though. Be that as it may, you're right, not always will the copy constructor be invoked...

Answer (score 1):

Then the arguments are *by value* they are copy-constructed (i.e. initialization).

Answer (score 0):

Initialization: (please check the [original-draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf))

> 5.2.2 Function call
>
> When a function is called, each parameter shall be **initialized** with its corresponding argument. [Such initializations are
> indeterminately sequenced with respect to each other] When a function
> is called, the parameters that have object type shall have
> completely-defined object type. [this still allows a parameter to be a
> pointer or reference to an incomplete class type. However, it prevents
> a passed-by-value parameter to have an incomplete class type.] *During
> the initialization of a parameter, an implementation may avoid the
> construction of extra temporaries by combining the conversions on the
> associated argument and/or the construction of temporaries with the
> initialization of the parameter.* The lifetime of a parameter ends when
> the function in which it is defined returns. *The initialization and
> destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling
> function.* [the access of the constructor, conversion functions or
> destructor is checked at the point of call in the calling function. If
> a constructor or destructor for a function parameter throws an
> exception, the search for a handler starts in the scope of the calling
> function; in particular, if the function called has a
> function-try-block with a handler that could handle the exception,
> this handler is not considered.]